# Error: Pandas requires version '1.1.0' or newer of 'xlrd' (version '1.0.0' currently installed)

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I've recently upgraded my Pandas version from `0.20.0` to `1.0.5` to be able to use the `explode()` function. Then when I tried reading an Excel file, it threw an error `Pandas requires version '1.1.0' or newer of 'xlrd' (version '1.0.0' currently installed).` So I installed `xlrd-1.2.0` using my Anaconda prompt and then restarted the kernel in my Jupyter notebook but I still keep getting the same error. Checking the `xlrd` version in the notebook using the following shows `1.0.0` as the installed version.

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("xlrd").version
```

I even tried `!pip install xlrd` in the notebook but it says `Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)`

I'm not sure what to do as I can't run any of my code now. Please help!

Comment: What command did you use to install `xlrd` with conda?

Comment: I used https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/ to download the `xlrd-1.2.0.tar.gz`. Unzipped the file and then used the Anaconda prompt to run `python setup.py build` and then `python setup.py install`. That's how I installed Pandas as well

Comment: Try running `pip install xlrd>=1.2.0`. You should not need to download a zip and install it manually if it's already on pypi.

Comment: The reason why I downloaded and installed was because I don't have admin rights on the machine

Comment: Well, you should probably work in a virtualenv (from `conda`, `virtualenv` or `venv`), in which case the right should be no issue (you don't need admin rights to install package in a virtual environment). If you do not use a virtualenv, you can `pip install --user` to install in user space. If the problem is that you cannot reach `pypi` using `pip` due to network rules, then you should probably download the `.whl` and do a `pip install XXX.whl`. Also, even if you use the `.tgz`, you should run `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I downloaded the `.whl` and did a `pip install` as you suggested and it seems to have worked, so thanks a lot! However, I think due to missing admin rights it fails to check conflicts...I guess that's ok

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue.
I got the same error. However i do not have Anaconda installed.
I managed to solve the issue with the below upgrade.

```
pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another package in Spyder. I solved it with pip install. Did you try that already?

Comment: `pip install xlrd>=1.2.0` says access denied since I don't have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in Colab when read .xls file
use upgrade pandas solve this

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas
```

I guess you can try this in local environment

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

In google-colab, this was the command that worked for me

```
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall xlrd
```